# Open closed sets intersection

Tags: general-topology

I have two non-empty sets $A$, which is closed, and $B$, which is open.

Let $\overline{X}$ be the closure of $X$.

I am really confused.... is it true that:

$A \cap \overline{B}\subseteq\overline{(A\cap B)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true in general. Take $A = [0,1]$ and $B = (1,2)$.

Then we have that $A\cap\overline{B} = \{1\}$ and $\overline{A\cap B} = \varnothing$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Hmm I see! Thank you! Maybe I have my subsets the wrong way around there...